# How to trigger a script via clicking a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with many tabs and I'm trying to create a dynamic Index tab.

So far this is what I'm doing:

```
function jumpToSheet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getActiveCell().getValue());
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}

function populateList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("D:D");
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++){
    cell = range.getCell(i+1, 1);
    cell.setValue(sheets[i].getName());
  }
}
```

I create two images on my index sheet. One has assigned to it the jumpToSheet function, the other has populateList assigned to it.

I click the second image and it populates column D with a list of all the tabs. (just a one time thing or whenever a tab is added/removed)

To navigate, I select a tab by name in this column, then click the first image and it takes me there.

I have two issues with this:

**How do I make it a one click action?** Currently I have to click the cell containing the name of the tab I want to jump to then click the image. I'd like to just click the cell if possible. Or any other solution that will only require a single click.

**How do I get back to the index tab with the keyboard?** I know I can jump around with ctrl+shift+pageup/down or click the horizontal lines icon in the lower left and select the top tab. But this is a bit slow for me. Is there a shortcut to go back to the first tab? Or some other way to do it quicker (preferably with the keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do it with one click. At minimum 2 clicks.
Make a menu with both commands, less clumsy than clicking images.
You could put a gas service url using hiperlink() but even that requires 2 clicks to go to the link and will be slower than the menu option.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to dynamically generate a bunch of images then, one per tab, with each having a script attached that would call the jumpToSheet() for that particular tab?

Comment: Doubt you can do it programstically but why you keep going the image route when you can use menus? Images are lame, you can't do many things like put them in frozen rows and can get deleted by a user etc

Comment: The frozen rows limitation has been very annoying for this application. My only issue with Menus is that they end up being close to identical with the functionality already present (the little button in the lower left that, when clicked, pops up with a list of all tabs) With the way I'm doing it now, the average clicks is slightly less than 2.

Comment: Panels however. I'm thinking I could make a panel that gets dynamically filled with buttons. I'm really trying to streamline the whole flow of use of this document (it gets heavy use, some 2,000 tab views a day)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I thought panels were a feature you could use in Google Spreadsheets.